# Does F# have a foldList function?

Tags: f#, fold

`Mathematica` and perhaps other languages have a `foldList` function. It is very much like `fold` but instead of returning only the final computed value it returns every intermediate value.

It is not hard to write a `foldList` function in F#:

```
let foldList f (x: 'S) (m: list<'T>) =
    let fs (xs: list<'S>) (y: 'T) = (f (Seq.head xs) y)::xs
    List.fold fs [x] m
    |> List.rev

let m = [1; 2; -3; 5]

foldList (+) 0 m
// val it : int list = [0; 1; 3; 0; 5]

List.fold (+) 0 m
// val it : int = 5
```

Is there such a function in F#? 
If not, is there a more efficient implementation than the one above?
Is there a way to avoid the call to List.rev?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is a built-in function, it's called [`List.scan`:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.scan%5B%27t,%27state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

```
let m = [1; 2; -3; 5]

List.scan (+) 0 m;;
//val it : int list = [0; 1; 3; 0; 5]
```

To answer your question about reversing the list, the implementation in FSharp.Core avoids reversing the list by using mutation.  This mutable API is not exposed publicly.  You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L351) if you're interested.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on _how_ mutation is happening in `List.rev`? I see the comment that says "mutation based implementation", but I fail to spot it. I can see the use of mutating code in other library function, but not for `List.rev`

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer You have misunderstood. The question was about avoiding the need to reverse the list.  Mutation is not happening in `List.rev`, it's happening in `List.scan` to avoid the requirement to reverse the list.

Comment: OK, makes sense now.

Comment: @TheInnerLight - Does the mutation in `scan` have implications for asynchronous, concurrent, or parallel processing?

Comment: @Soldalma No, not externally, `scan` doesn't mutate the list you supply, just the local list it builds as a return value.  If the implementation of `scan` within FSharp.Core made use of some of the above techniques then it's certainly true that it could cause unwanted behaviour.  Thankfully though, it doesn't do this.

Comment: So if I call scan from two different threads there will be no problem?

Comment: @Soldalma Correct.